# RTSP to RTMP using Xuggler and red5 - Out stream could not open in Container.cpp

Tags: red5, vlc, rtmp, ip-camera, xuggler

My requirement is Streaming IPCamera RTSP stream to RTMP stream. I have setup a application using livemedia 555 + VLC + Red5 + Xuggler. I successfully multistreaming using vlc as sdp file in locally. Now the problem comes in red5 + xuggler side

I am using [steamStream](http://www.red5wiki.com/wiki/SteamStream) red5 application for restreming. The error is below

```
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - SsPlaybackSecurity isPlaybackAllowed() called.  name is: guest
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - streamSubscriberStart() called... stream: 2d5fd53d-ab1d-46b2-ac23-a60d9e9c7d8e
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - streamPlaylistItemPlay() called... stream: 2d5fd53d-ab1d-46b2-ac23-a60d9e9c7d8e | item: guest | isLive?: Yes
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Stream subscriber count is zero; starting a new ReStreamer.  Stream: guest
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - ReStreamer constructor called.
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Client connecting; incrementing stream count for stream 'guest' from 0 to 1.
[INFO] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - ReStreamer thread starting.  ID: 38
[DEBUG] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - ReStreamer: About to register output stream with provider service: guest
[DEBUG] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - ReStreamer: Successfully registered and started output stream: guest
[INFO] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Publishing stream from input: /opt/red5-0.9.1/webapps/IPcameraStreamer/sdpdescriptors/guest.sdp
[DEBUG] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Publishing stream to output: redfive:guest
[DEBUG] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Got packet with key frame data; setting up coders: guest
[ERROR] [Thread-3] com.xuggle.xuggler - URL: redfive:guest; Error: could not open file (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:513)
[INFO] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Parameters: com.xuggle.xuggler.IMetaData@739036864[]
[INFO] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Parameters Rejected: com.xuggle.xuggler.IMetaData@738595792[]
[ERROR] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - Exception occurred during restreaming: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open output container at URL: redfive:guest
[INFO] [Thread-3] net.arulraj.ipcam.Application - ReStreamer thread exiting.  ID: 38
```

- Local multiple streaming is done using vlc server
- sdp file created using vlc
- Red5 reads the sdp file as input
- Now I got the error while writing sdp input into rtmp output.

Error in [Container.cpp](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp) file line no 513.

I am using

- CentOS 6 x86_64 OS
- Java 1.6
- Xuggler 5.4
- red5-0.9.1

I followed this tutorial http://flance.onego.ru/2010/08/02/238

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of that article... 8).
I had to use Red5 revision 3894 from SVN. Next versions of Red5 did not work for me.